# Math to find the group an items falls within

Tags: php, math

I am working on a problem matching items in JS and I need to calculate the group a number falls within. Here is my issue.

group1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
group2: 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
group3: 17,18,19,20,21

Given and item number, what is the formula to give the group number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you would do `Math.floor((yourNumber-1)/8))`.

Demo:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 21; i++)
    console.log(i + " -> " + Math.floor((i-1)/8));
```

Output:

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 0
4 -> 0
5 -> 0
6 -> 0
7 -> 0
8 -> 0
9 -> 1
10 -> 1
11 -> 1
12 -> 1
13 -> 1
14 -> 1
15 -> 1
16 -> 1
17 -> 2
18 -> 2
19 -> 2
20 -> 2
21 -> 2
```

Comment: Because the group size was 8.